# Can't show the right URL in my iPad simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm building an iPad app and that's a browser. I have a little problem because in a text field, I can write any web direction, such http://www.google.com/. The problem is that when I change the page, at, for example, http://www.apple.com/ , it stills says google. I have written the code, but I don't know why it doesn't work!

```
-(void)currentURL{
int i= 0;
while (i == 0) {
    url = [request URL];

    NSLog(@"%@", url.absoluteString);

    textfield.text = url.absoluteString;  
}}
```

Please I need some help!

Comment: What's the purpose of the while loop in the code snippet you've posted? Also, what type is 'request'?

Comment: no kidding!  get rid of that horrid `while`, which basically compiles into an infinite loop.

Comment: Explain better your code. While the loop? And while `url.absoluteString` is assigned to `textfield.text`.

Comment: Ok. First I write the same code in the following method to search:-(IBAction)buttonpressed:(id)sender{
    
    url=[NSURL URLWithString:[field text]];
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [web loadRequest:request];
    [web isEqual:field.text];
    
    
}                                                                                 The problem was that the URL only refreshed when I pressed the button, so I thought that if something loops all the time it will be all the time refreshed

Comment: So ..... is your problem solved?  If yes, mark one of the answers as "accepted" and upvote helpful ones (which is the way you can *credit* anyone for helping you here).  If not, you should edit your original question for your new code and restate your problem.

Comment: It's half-sloved. I know now what I have to do but I don't know how to do it.(what I want to do is the 1st answer)

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
    textfield.text = url.absoluteString;
```

with this:

```
if(textfield)
{
    if(url)
    {
        textfield.text = [url absoluteString];
    } else {
        NSLog( @"my request or URL is nil");
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"I didn't set my textfield");
}
```

Comment: No. And I don't know why. I think I'm gonna erase all and make a different code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the web view delegate which will tell you when the page inside the web view changes, e.g. when the user clicks a link. You can then use the delegate methods to update your text field to the new URL.

if you've done that and your textfield isn't updating, you've probably forgotten to connect your textfield in your nib file to the textfield outlet of your class, so your self.textfield property is nil and setting its text does nothing.

Comment: OK. You're answer is right, but I don't know if I have implemented the webViewDelegate protocol well. I've just written in the .m "@protocol UIWebViewDelegate;",is it right?

Comment: In your view controller header file, add <UIWebviewDelegate> to the class interface definition, e.g. MyViewController : UIViewController<UIWebviewDelegate> { ... }. In Interface builder, bind the delegate outlet of the webview to your view controller, now look up UIWebviewDelegate in the docs and add the methods you need to your view controller to handle when the webview loads a new page.